# Qt QByteArray drived class

Tags: qt

I Have problem with my drived Class

```
 class Myclass:public QByteArray 
{
public :
Myclass();
}

Myclass::Myclass()
:QByteArray ()
{


}
```

the problem when i try treat Myclass as QByteArray : Myclass tt("fooo");

Comment: You should add the error you get!

Comment: It doesn't make sense to inherit from QByteArray: It's destructor is non-virtual and it has no virtual methods, so there is nothing to reimplement. If you pass a Myclass object instead of a QByteArray it will be sliced, if you delete a QByteArray* which is actually a Myclass, you might leak memory. If you want to add functionality, better make the QByteArray a member of your class, or have free functions taking the QByteArray as argument.

Comment: @alrawab I recommend to hear the warning above. most of the "data" classes in Qt are not meant to be inherited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you do not have a constructor which takes C string argument.

Constructors are not inherited, you must add every constructor you need to your class, even if you are just going to call a superclass constructor and nothing else.

Example:

```
MyClass::MyClass(const char *cstr) : QByteArray(cstr) {}
```

Comment: thaks it's okay i solved by building two constructors